# После JS не работает CSS

Tags: jquery, css

Столкнулся с такой вот проблемой. В скрытом блоке содержаться `Slick-slider`, после того, как блок активирую, изображения появляются в миниатюрном виде

[image: Маленькие иконки]

Если пролистать `slider` все опять стает как нужно.

[image: Нормальное изображение]

Код самый простой

```
$('.description').click(function () {
    $('#content-1').show()
});
```

Без `JQuery` все работает нормально. Что бы это могло быть?? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вероятно как обычно - из-за скрытности при загрузке страницы, слайдер плохо инициализируется. Попробуйте вместо display:none поиграть с другими способами скрытия (opacity:0 / visibility:hidden / margin-top:-100% ) и overflow:hidden . Т.е. чтобы слайдер как бы был на странице, но невидим.

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос решен. Нужно использовать overflow: hidden; и .stop().fadeToggle()